# Whats means the notation "2." in C++?

Tags: c++

I don't understand the means of notation 2. in this line.

```
   return 2.;
```

I am looking at an example in C ++ which calculates the matrix permanent and I am not able to understand what this notation means.

Comment: it means return 2.0

Comment: It means someone got lazy and didn't type in a `0`.

Comment: On a side note, whoever wrote this code should be sentenced to typing 80 `0` before breakfast.

Comment: Someone must really hate 0's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). It's a `double` with the value `2.0`. Just `2` would be an `int` with the value `2`. Adding a decimal point (even if you don't provide decimals) makes it a floating point literal. You can also add a suffix to change it's type. Notably `2.f` for a `float` and `2.l` for a `long double`.

Answer (score 3):

`2.` is a [floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).  It tells the compiler to return the value of 2 as a `double`.  The `.` is needed to tell the compiler that you want a floating point type instead of a integral type.

In C++ all literals have a type and there are certain ways to differentiate them from one another.  `2` for instance is an `int`, `2.` is a `double` , `2.f`/`2.0f` would be a `float`